# getting custom fields in doctrine 2

Tags: symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I have an entity as follow:

```
private $username;
private $password;
private $createdAt; //datetime
```

I want to run the query in doctrine to get the entities with the existing fields plus another field (in this case a column showing difference of createdAt and current datetime in minutes.
In sql I would run query like:

```
 select username, password, createdAt,TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE , created_at, NOW()) AS minutes from users
```

In doctrine I fetched the entity as below:

```
 $user = $em->getRepository('TestBundle:Users');
```

How can I get the custom field minutes from doctrine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should check [ResultSetMapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html):

And check how to add [scalar result](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html#scalar-results)

```
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping;
$rsm->addEntityResult('Users', 'u');
$rsm->addFieldResult('u', 'id', 'id');
$rsm->addFieldResult('u', 'password', 'password');
$rsm->addScalarResult('minutes', 'minutes');

$query = $this->_em->createNativeQuery('select username, password, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE , created_at, NOW()) AS minutes', $rsm);

$users = $query->getResult();
```

Comment: does createNativeQuery returns an resultset(array) or an entity ?

Comment: Above query will return an array which contains an user object and scalar field minutes. if you remove scalar field, it would be user entity.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up the function inside your Entity like

```
function GetDifference() {
     return getField1() - getField2()
}
```

Then that will be available for you every object

EDIT:
Its very easy. Just like any other function

```
function getDateDifference() {
return abs(strtotime($createdAT) - strtotime($now));
}
```

Comment: well the logic here lies in the php which i have been currently doing, but i want to perform this within the mysql query.